# Why Application recompile every few minutes on IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an Web Application which for unknown reason recompile every few minutes  and results an application restarts (not recycle) once every 10-15 minutes when it reached the max recompile limit.

After I added healthMonitoring configuration in the web.config file (according to this [article](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-understand-why-did-the-application-restart)) I could see the recompilation events on the EventLog but not what triggered it:

```
10:00:03 AM Event message: Application compilation is starting.
10:03:44 AM Event message: Application compilation is starting.
10:05:27 AM Event message: Application compilation is starting.
10:08:01 AM Event message: Application compilation is starting.
10:10:48 AM Event message: Application is shutting down. Reason: Maximum number of recompilations was reached. 
10:10:48 AM Event message: Application is starting. 
10:12:27 AM Event message: Application compilation is starting.
10:14:26 AM Event message: Application compilation is starting.
```

Additional information:

- Only when the application is first recycled it will start the shutting down events every 15 recompiles, before the recycle I can only see the recompile events and it will not shut down the application
- Anti Virus scanner is disabled on the server
- There are other web application installed on the same machine which does not suffer from this issue
- Machine is Windows server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5

How can I find what is triggering the recompile?

Comment: I have same issue, same server.  Any answer yet?